# Execute in main thread with boost::future::then

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

compiler : mingw4.8.2
os : win7 32bits

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_CONTINUATION

#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{

    std::cout<<"main thread id : "<<boost::this_thread::get_id()<<std::endl;
    boost::future<int> f1 = boost::async(boost::launch::async, []()
    {
        std::cout<<"async thread id : "<<boost::this_thread::get_id()<<std::endl;
        return 123;
    });
    boost::future<std::string> f2 = f1.then(boost::launch::deferred, [](boost::future<int> f)
    {
            std::cout<<"then id : "<<boost::this_thread::get_id()<<std::endl;
            return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(f.get());
    });

    f2.wait();
}
```

result :

```
main thread id : 3758
async thread id : 33b4
then id : 3824
```

How could I make the lambda expression pass in to "then" run in the main thread?Anyway to ask it run in the main thread? If there are no easy way to do it by boost, is it possible to to do asynchronous wait with the help of Qt(when future is ready, emit the signal and run the function in the main thread)?

**edit** : The purpose of f1.then

boost::async may run some heavy task, it would most likely block the gui if I don't let this task run on another thread.After the task done, I want to tell the gui and execute some actions related to gui, that is why I use f1.then, because in this way I don't need to block the function.

**edit** : looks like deferred can work

```
//cout has not thread safe guarantee, but adding mutex at here will cause dead lock...
std::cout<<"main thread id : "<<boost::this_thread::get_id()<<std::endl;
auto f1 = boost::async(boost::launch::async, [&]()
{
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds( 5 ));
    std::cout<<"async thread id : "<<boost::this_thread::get_id()<<std::endl;
    return 123;
});
auto f2 = f1.then(boost::launch::deferred, [&](decltype(f1) f)
{
        std::cout<<"then result : "<<f.get()<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"then id : "<<boost::this_thread::get_id()<<std::endl;
        return std::string("result get");
});


for(size_t i = 0; i != 50; ++i){
    std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
}

f2.wait();
```

Comment: But if you want that, why did you define f2 as a continuation of f1 in the first place ? why not `f1.wait()` and then execute the lambda in the main directly ?

Comment: @quantdev I add f2 only to see which threads they execute in

Comment: Ok, but why do you use `then` on `f1` if you want the lambda to be executed in the main thread ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<typename F>
 future<typename boost::result_of<F( future&)>::type>
then(F&& func); // EXTENSION
template<typename S, typename F>
 future<typename boost::result_of<F( future&)>::type>
then(S& scheduler, F&& func); // EXTENSION NOT_YET_IMPLEMENTED
template<typename F>
 future<typename boost::result_of<F( future&)>::type>
then(launch policy, F&& func); // EXTENSION
```

from [future documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.unique_future.then). You should use third version of function.

```
f1.then(boost::launch::deferred, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will run in the thread same as the async function call(the one with std::cout<<"async thread id : "), but not run in the main thread

Comment: @StereoMatching Did you try it? The [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures) say, "A launch policy of either `boost::launch::async`, which asks the runtime to create an asynchronous thread, or `boost::launch::deferred`, which indicates you simply want to defer the function call until a later time (lazy evaluation). Depending on the launch policy, the task is either run asynchronously on its own thread or **synchronously on whichever thread calls the wait() or get() member functions** on that future."